# Writing the XML/ String to the response is taking longer time HttpServletResponse getWriter write

Tags: java, performance, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have a method in controller(Servlet) which return a XML string as a response based on request sent. However, sometimes below mentioned method took longer time and sometimes not.Even though the response string(XML) size is same.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

   String request = req.getParameter("searchXml");
   String code = req.getParameter("Service_Code");

   String response = controlEngine.getResponseXML(request, code);

   resp.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");      
   resp.getWriter().write(response);

}
```

Why writing the XML to the response is taking longer time sometimes. The response size is same however, sometimes it took 1.5 seconds to execute and sometimes it took 300 milliseconds.

```
   resp.getWriter().write(response);
```

"Why it's taking 1.5 seconds to execute above line ?"

Comment: There does not seem to anything apparent with the code. Could be environment e.g. slow network connection, JVM memory etc. could be a reason

Comment: Consumer(Request sender) and Producer(Returning Response) are on same local machine. 
Have high configuration machine i will check and update about JVM memory.

Comment: Strange, try flushing the writer (not closing).